# PHP RegEx: match a list in an unknown order

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match some CSS properties. However, I cannot predict the order they will be in.

Example:

```
header p {
color:#f2f3ed;
background-color:#353535;
background-image: url(../images/dots.png);
}
```

However, I should also expect:

```
header p {
background-image: url(../images/dots.png);
background-color:#353535;
color:#f2f3ed;
}
```

And any other combination of these three properties. The web application we are building only gives me access to the `preg_match` function.

Anyone know a way to match every possible combination of properties? I know exactly what the properties will be, I just do not know which order they will come in.

Saying that, I am trying to find a quicker solution than typing out every possible combination and separating it with `|`

Comment: You should use a CSS parser instead of regular expressions only here.

Comment: You could also technically call `preg_match` multiple times, once for each property you wish to match, but a parser is the best way to go if this is code that needs to be maintained or used by others.

Comment: I attempted to build a regex for this but it fried my noodle with having the selector at the front with many matches in the middle.

Comment: You could also use preg_match_all if that's available and use it to iterate all the lines.

Answer (score 1):

The super-inexact but also stupidly-easy approach would be use a list of alternatives:

```
/  ( \s* color:#\w+; | \s* bbb:... | \s* ccc:... ){3}  /x
```

The quantifier `{3}` will ensure that three of the alternatives are present, and the order won't matter.

It would however allow three `color:` properties to match. You'll have to decide if that's important enough, or if it's unlikely enough that anyone will write three consecutive `color:` statements in your CSS declarations.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex for existence of some words whose order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656131/regex-for-existence-of-some-words-whose-order-doesnt-matter#)

This works, thanks to the lookahead operator (?= ).

```regex
/^(?=.*(?:color|background-color|background-image)\:.*?;).*/gm
```

or with comments

```regex
^            # beggining of line
(?=          # positive lookahead (true if pattern present after current position; in this case the beginning of current line)
  .*         # anything before the pattern we search for
  (?:color|background-color|background-image)\:      # match any of those 3 sequences followed by : char
  .*?;       # anything followed by ; but not looking beyond the first ; found
  )
.*           # match the rest of the chars from where the (?= ) was found.
/gmx         # MODIFIERS: global, multi-line, extended (for comments, ignores spaces and anything after #)
```

You can try it here:

https://regex101.com/r/tX0hK3/1

The ^ before (?=.* is very important for efficiency! 
Otherwise the engine would try the search once for each position.

The ending .* (or .+ or .++, possessive) is just for matching the line now we have find the right content.