# use regular expression in python to find two strings in line

Tags: python, regex

I just need to know HOW to search for TWO strings in a line of my file.

Example: I need the line to include both "protein_coding" and "exon". 
Then if it does include them I will print certain columns of each line. I know how to print them but cannot figure out how to search for TWO strings using reg ex.
Thank you in advance.

is this correct?:
if re.match("protein_coding" & "exon" in line:

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656131/regex-for-existience-of-some-words-whose-order-doesnt-matter/24656216#24656216

Comment: I am hopeful this question is already asked and has an answer... Duplicate questions are not sign ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the test strings do not require the use of a regular expression, recall that you can use Python's string functions and `in` as well:

```
>>> line='protein_coding other stuff exon more stuff'
>>> "protein_coding" in line and "exon" in line
True
```

Or if you want to test an arbitrary number of words, use `all` and a tuple of targets words to test:

```
>>> line='protein_coding other stuff exon more stuff'
>>> all(s in line for s in ("protein_coding", "exon", "words"))
False
>>> all(s in line for s in ("protein_coding", "exon", "stuff"))
True
```

And if the matches are something that require a regex and you want to limit to multiple unrelated regexes, use `all` and a comprehension to test:

```
>>> p1=re.compile(r'\b[a-z]+_coding\b')
>>> p2=re.compile(r'\bexon\b')
>>> li=[p.search(line) for p in [p1, p2]]
>>> li
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10856d988>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10856d9f0>]
>>> all(e for e in li)
True
```

Comment: @dahlia: If this is useful, please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 3):

This regex would match the lines which has both "protein_coding" & "exon" strings.

```
^.*?\bprotein_coding\b.*?\bexon\b.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yB3gO3/5)

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """protein_coding exon foo bar
... foo
... protein_coding
... """
>>> m = re.findall(r'^.*?\bprotein_coding\b.*?\bexon\b.*$', data, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
protein_coding exon foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Using anchors and lookahead assertions:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^(?=.*protein_coding)(?=.*exon).+$', data)
```

The inline `(?m)` modifier enables multi-line mode. The use of lookahead here matches both substrings regardless of the order they are in.

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mU1uS3/2)