# Regex with exclusion chars and another regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How to write regex which find word (without whitespace) that doesn't contain some chars (like `*` or `#`) and sentence also (like `level10` or `level2` - it should be also regex - `level[0-9]+`). It will be simple for chars excluded (`[^\\s^#^*]+`) but how to exclude this `'level'` example too ?

I want to exclude chars AND level with number.

1. Examples:

   - weesdlevel3fv - shouldn't match because of 'level3'
   - we3rlevelw4erw - should match - there is level without number
   - dfs3leveldfvws#3vd - shouldn't match - level is good, but '#' char appeared
   - level4#level levelw4_level - threat as two words because of whitespaces - only second one should match - no levels with number and no restricted chars like '#' or '*'

Comment: Please give more examples of valid and invalid input, and show what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

See this regex:

```
/(?<=\s)(?!\S*[#*])(?!\S*level[0-9])\S+/
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `(?<=\s)` Asserts position after a whitespace sequence.
- `(?!\S*[#*])` Asserts that **"#"** or **"*"** is absent in the sequence.
- `(?!\S*level[0-9])` Asserts that **`level[0-9]`** is not matched in the sequence.
- `\S+`Now that our conditionals pass, this sequence is valid. Go ahead and use `\S+` or `\S++` to match the entire sequence.

To use lookaheads more exclusively, you can add another `(?!\S*<false_to_assert>)` group.

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/gN4sQ7/4)

---

For this specific case you can [use a *double negation trick*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17912155#17912155):

```
/(?<=\s)(?!\S*level[0-9])[^\s#*]+(?=\s)/
```

[Another regex demo.](http://regex101.com/r/gN4sQ7/3)

---

**Read more:**

- [Regex for existence of some words whose order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656216/3622940)

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation. I tried it at 'weesdlevel3fv we3rlevel4erw dfsdfv#levels3vd fvlevels3vd' - should match last word but match last 3

Comment: @Archaon In [tag:regex], a `word` is defined as a collection of `\w` (word characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) surrounded by `\W` (non-word characters). I _assume_ you meant that you are looking to match non-whitespace sequences (`\S`) between whitespaces (`\s`) then?

Comment: +1 for efficient use of [classic password validation technique](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can simply OR the searches with the pipe character
`[^\s#*]+|level[0-9]+`