# ?= and ?P combined in a regex

Tags: python, regex

**in short :**
I want to use the [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) technique in Python with the `?P<name>` convention (details [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)) to get the groups by name.

**more details :**

I discovered the Lookahead trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656131/regex-for-existence-of-some-words-whose-order-doesnt-matter); e.g. the following regex...

```
/^(?=.*Tim)(?=.*stupid).+
```

... allows to detect strings like `"Tim stupid"` or `"stupid Tim"`, the order being not important.

I can't figure out how I can combine the `?=` "operator" with the `?P` one; the following regex **obviously** doesn't do the trick but gives an idea of what I want :

```
/^(?=?P<word1>.*Tim)(?=?P<word2>.*stupid).+
```

Comment: Do you mean [`^(?=(?P<word1>.*Tim))(?=(?P<word2>.*stupid)).+`](https://regex101.com/r/wW3bR3/1)?

Comment: @suizokukan: A *capturing* group is a `(...)`. The `(?=...)` are *lookaheads*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?P<word1>` in your regex reminds of a [*named capture group*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups):

> The syntax for a named group is one of the Python-specific extensions: `(?P<name>...)`. `*name*` is, obviously, the name of the group. Named groups also behave exactly like capturing groups, and additionally associate a name with a group.

So, most probably you are looking for a way to *capture* substrings inside a positive lookahead anchored at the start to require a string to meet both patterns, and capture the substrings inside both the lookaheads:

```
^(?=(?P<word1>.*Tim))(?=(?P<word2>.*stupid)).+
    ^^^^^^^^^^     ^    ^^^^^^^^^^        ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW3bR3/1)

Note that if you do not need the string itself, `.+` is redundant and can be removed. You might want to re-adjust the borders of the named capture groups if necessary.

Comment: More accurately (?) :  `^(?=.*(?P<word1>Tim))(?=.*(?P<word2>stupid)).+ `