# Regex for matching adjacent words where order doesn't matter

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex with python and trying to figure out the best way to match a pattern where the order of two words I'm searching for doesn't matter, but they must be adjacent. So for example, I'm searching for either the phrase `"fat cat lasagna co"` or `"cat fat lasagna co"`, and I have to imagine there's a better way than just `r"\b(fat cat|cat fat) lasagna co\b"`

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656131/regex-for-existence-of-some-words-whose-order-doesnt-matter) which addressed a similar problem but the words didn't have to be adjacent and couldn't figure out how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: I think your proposed solution is probably the best you'll find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no strictly *better* solution, but there's an alternative.

Now, if you have two normal words like "fat" and "cat", then `(fat cat|cat fat)` is undoubtedly the best solution. But what if you have 5 words? Or if you have more complex patterns than just `fat` and `cat` that you don't want to type twice?

Say instead of `fat` and `cat` you have 3 regex patterns `A`, `B` and `C`, and instead of the space between `fat` and `cat` you have the regex pattern `S`. In that case, you could use this recipe:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1(?:S))(?:(?!\2)()(?:A)|(?!\3)()(?:B)|(?!\4)()(?:C))){3}
```

If you don't have an `S`, this can be simplified to

```
(?:(?!\1)()(?:A)|(?!\2)()(?:B)|(?!\3)()(?:C)){3}
```

<sup>(Note: `(?:X)` can be simplified to `X` if `X` doesn't contain an alternation `|`.)</sup>

### Example

If we set `A` = `fat`, `B` = `cat` and `S` = space, we get:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1 )(?:(?!\2)()fat|(?!\3)()cat)){2}
```

[Try it online.](https://regex101.com/r/CkWUYk/1)

---

### Explanation

In essence, we're using capture groups to "remember" which patterns have already matched. To do so, we use this little pattern here:

```
(?!\1)()some_pattern
```

What does this do? It's a regex that matches exactly once. Once it has matched, it won't ever match again. If you try to add a quantifier around that pattern like `(?:(?!\1)()some_pattern)*` it'll match either once or won't match at all.

The trick there is the usage of a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to a capture group before that group has even been defined. Because capture groups are initialized with a "failed to match" state, the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\1)` will match successfully - but only the first time. Because right afterwards, the capture group `()` matches and captures the empty string. From this point forward, the negative lookahead `(?!\1)` will never match again.

With this as a building block, we can create a regex that matches `fatcat` and `catfat` while only containing the words `fat` and `cat` once:

```
(?:(?!\1)()fat|(?!\2)()cat){2}
```

Because of the negative lookaheads, each word can only match at most once. Adding a `{2}` quantifier at the end guarantees that each of the two words matches *exactly* once, or the entire match fails.

Now we just need to find a way to match a space between `fat` and `cat`. Well, that's just a slight variation of the same pattern:

```
(?:(?!\1)()|\1 )
```

This pattern will match the empty string on its first match, and on each subsequent match it'll match a space.

Put it all together, and voilà:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1 )(?:(?!\2)()fat|(?!\3)()cat)){2}
```

---

### Templates (for the lazy)

2 patterns `A` and `B`, with separator `S`:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1(?:S))(?:(?!\2)()(?:A)|(?!\3)()(?:B))){2}
```

3 patterns `A`, `B` and `C`, with separator `S`:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1(?:S))(?:(?!\2)()(?:A)|(?!\3)()(?:B)|(?!\4)()(?:C))){3}
```

4 patterns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, with separator `S`:

```
(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1(?:S))(?:(?!\2)()(?:A)|(?!\3)()(?:B)|(?!\4)()(?:C)|(?!\5)()(?:D))){4}
```

2 patterns `A` and `B`, without `S`:

```
(?:(?!\1)()(?:A)|(?!\2)()(?:B)){2}
```

3 patterns `A`, `B` and `C`, without `S`:

```
(?:(?!\1)()(?:A)|(?!\2)()(?:B)|(?!\3)()(?:C)){3}
```

4 patterns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, without `S`:

```
(?:(?!\1)()(?:A)|(?!\2)()(?:B)|(?!\3)()(?:C)|(?!\4)()(?:D)){4}
```