# Javascript regex to emulate css 'double bar' combinator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that works in Javascript and emulates the [double bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Double_bar) combinator for css rules.

The way double bar works:

- all entities are optional
- each entity can can appear at most once
- at least one of them must be present
- they may appear in any order

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610067/679612) answer which works perfectly except it doesn't work in Javascript

I spent a while trying to reformulate it to make it work in Javascript but I haven't had any luck.

```
^(?:(?:(?!\1)()|\1 )(?:(?!\2)()fat|(?!\3)()cat)){1,2}$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/CkWUYk/3) is a link to the regex (Python) that shows it working as intended

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/CkWUYk/2) is a link to the same regex to show it doesn't work in Javascript

Comment: It is a known difference. JS regexp engine initializes all captures with an empty string while Python `re` keeps them as `null`.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same achieve the same effect in JS?

Comment: Are you planning to create the pattern dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, I'm creating the regex programatically. Additionally, fat and cat will themselves be more complicated regexes to match css values

Comment: This pattern works well for two terms but it is not expandable to 3+ terms

https://regex101.com/r/8GFcTs/2

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear but each word can only appear at most once. I updated the question

Comment: Why use regex if you just may split with spaces, check if all the values are in your list?