# Regex to look for any order of patterns in python

Tags: python, regex

I have been searching around but couldn't find the answer.

I want to look for a 3 letter pattern where 2 of them should be either D or E and the third one can be anything. And the order doesn't matter.

For example: **DEA or ESD or DZE or PDE** should all match.
For a sample string like this 'EDEDEDADEDE', overlapping patterns should also be detected so 'EDE', 'DED', 'EDE', 'DED', 'EDA', 'DAD', 'ADE', 'DED', 'EDE' should all be in the search.

What I can think of is: `[A-Z][DE]{2}|[DE][A-Z][DE]|[DE]{2}[A-Z]` but this seems clunky. Any simpler solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the input is of length 3, then this regex would be simpler `[DE].?[DE]`

Comment: Note that `[DE].?[DE]` fails for "PDE".

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/BNI35Z/1?

Comment: Like kungphu pointed out, the order doesn't matter. I don't know where the D or E will be.

Comment: In comments to answers you mention you also need to match cases like "DPD". Please update your question to contain such test cases. As it is right now it can be understood like you want BOTH "d" and "e" and a third letter in your match. You failed to mention that for example "D" can occur twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this; it's much more readable without.

```
valid = ("D" in s) and ("E" in s)
```

If you also need to validate length, just stick `len(s) == 3` on before the letter checks.

If you're required to use regex, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656216/833881) seems to have the details covered.

```
import re

DE = re.compile(r"(?=.*D)(?=.*E)")

all(map(DE.match, ("DEA", "ESD", "DZE", "PDE")))
# True
all(map(DE.match, ("DEA", "ESD", "DZE", "PDE", "QQQ")))
# False
```

*Edit: Note that this assumes both D and E must be present in the string, which matches the provided examples but not really the problem statement, on the assumption that the problem statement was not exactly accurate.*

Comment: Hi, this 3 letter pattern will be part of my regex search. I don't know how long it will be as long as it contains this at the beginning.

Comment: Then I'd just run the regex or other check against `str[0:3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?=[^\s]{0,2}D)(?=[^\s]{0,2}E)...`

It first assures, that what follows is a word (string of characters, except white spaces, achieved with nagetiva character class `[^\s]`) containing `D` and `E`.

For each letter there is separate positive lookahead:

- `(?=[^\s]{0,2}D)` for `D`,
- `(?=[^\s]{0,2}E)` for `E`.

If those are satisfied, then match three characters with `...`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SR8WPt/1)

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation on how this works? Especially what is happening inside the lookaheads?

Comment: @Asunez I just added explanation :)

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, each lookahead is looking for 2 non-whitespace characters and a letter D/E afterwards - but how does this work for DZE, where D is before, not after, the non-whitespace character?

Comment: @Asunez Everything is explained, if you have doubts, look at demo I provided. It works with `DZE` also. Pattern simply looks at closest word and looks for `D` and `E` separately, at most "two non-white space characters away".

Comment: This failed to capture DFD in one of my trials.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\b(?=.?[DE].?[DE])[A-Z]{3}\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b              : word boundary
    (?=         : start lookahead, zero-length assertin that make sure we have
        .?      : optional any character
        [DE]    : D or E
        .?      : optional any character
        [DE]    : D or E
    )           : end lookahead
    [A-Z]{3}    : A capital letter, must appear 3 times
\b              : word boundary
```

**See it in action:**

https://regex101.com/r/uo7tv8/2

Python implementation:

```
str = 'For example: DEA or ESD or DZE or PDE should all match, but not DEDE ABC DEF GHI JKL.'
regex = r"\b(?=.?[DE].?[DE])[A-Z]{3}\b"
print re.findall(regex, str)
```

**Output:**

```
['DEA', 'ESD', 'DZE', 'PDE', 'DEF']
```

---

## Edit according to comment:

```
str = 'ADFDFAGERASDFSAERSEDSEDEFADF'
regex = r"(?=.?[DE].?[DE])[A-Z]{3}"
print re.findall(regex, str)
```

**Output:**

```
['ADF', 'SED', 'SED']
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I ran the search and it found nothing.

Comment: Are there other characer arround those 3 ones. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52601558/edit) and add some test cases, sample text and expected result. My regex works for string that contain only 3 letters as you can see in the link to regex101

Comment: @Josh: You may want to replace anchors `^` and `$` with word boundary `\b` at the beginning and at the end of the regex.

Comment: here is a test string you can try: 'ADFDFAGERASDFSAERSEDSEDEFADF'. You are supposed to fnd 'DFD', 'SED', 'SED'

Comment: @Josh: This not what you have explain in your question. As I said above, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52601558/edit) and add some test cases, sample text and expected result. What should be the result for `DEDEDEDE`?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I edited my quesiton and included a sample string. Per your question: 'DED', 'EDE', 'DED', 'EDE', 'DED', 'EDE' 6 patterns should be detected.