# Match a string between two or more words regardless of order

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regular expression that matches words regardless of order. As an example, these lines should match with the marked range,

```
A longword1 B longword2 C
  ^-------------------^

A longword2 B longword1 C
  ^-------------------^
```

while these shouldn't:

```
A longword1 B longword1 C
A longword2 B longword2 C
A longword1 B
A longword2 C
```

(A, B, C are fillers, they can be essentially any text)

It *is* possible to just use alternations, such as: `\b((longword1).*?(longword2)|(longword2).*?(longword2))\b`. But the regex would grow factorially, i.e. three words would need 3! alternates. It's also possible to use subroutines, e.g. `\b((?'A'longword1).*?(?'B'longword2')|(?P>B).*?(?P>A))\b`. Although shorter, I would still need to include all of its permutations.

Now I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656131/regex-for-existence-of-some-words-whose-order-doesnt-matter/24656216), but the accepted answers don't exactly solve my problem. Using `\b(?=.*longword1)(?=.*longword2).*\b` would match the whole line instead of the range I've shown.

I understand, that it would be much easier if I checked the sentence against a list of words. But my current use case prevents it from being possible; I can only use regexes.

Here are some links to demonstrate what I meant:

**EXPECTED:**

- Using alternates: https://regexr.com/5b6pv
- Using subroutines: https://regexr.com/5b6ss

**INCORRECT:**

- Using positive lookahead (as linked): https://regexr.com/5b6q2

Are there any simpler regex(es) to tackle this?

Comment: Put `A` and `C` around the solution from the other post.

Comment: @Barmar I can't find the solution you mention. What do you mean?

Comment: `A.*\b(?=.*longword1)(?=.*longword2).*\b.*C`

Comment: @Barmar But it matches from `A` to `C`. OP only needs to match a substring from word1 to word2. `A` and `C` are just fillers, they denote any text. And the word 1 and word 2 can be swapped. And there can be more than two words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a backreference + a subroutine:

```
\b(longword1|longword2)\b.*?\b(?!\1\b)(?1)\b
```

Expanding it for three alternatives:

```
\b(longword1|longword2|longword3)\b.*?\b(?!\1\b)((?1))\b.*?\b(?!(?:\1|\2)\b)(?1)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJwU7o/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJwU7o/2), too. So, the list of words will be in Group 1, and you will only need to add backreferences before the subsequent subroutines.

**Details**

- `\b(longword1|longword2)\b` - a whole word, either `longword1` or `longword2`
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\1\b)` - there cannot be the same text as matched in Group 1 followed with a word boundary
- `(?1)` - a subroutine that matches the same pattern as in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: Just curious, will this syntax heavily impact the performance of the regex?

Comment: @NickyLogan Sure it will. But alternation would cause even more backtracking.

Comment: Great! I thought I know regexes pretty good but when I stuck on a task like this and found your solution, I understood I don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Perl regular expressions (PCRE), you can make use of the `\K` operator to help with lookaround to get what you need. For example: `(longword1)(longword2)|.*\K(?1).*(?2)|.*\K(?2).*(?1)`

Here is an demo for you: https://regex101.com/r/Qo00Hk/1